# How can I name the saving bitmap file as the content of a textbox?

Tags: c#, if-statement, textbox, save

My application needs to save a JPEG image file with a file name provided in a TextBox. I don't want to use SaveFileDialog because I don't want the user to see the dialog or be able to change the location of the saved image.

How can I set the name of the saved file from a TextBox?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox4.Text.Length >= 1)
       bitmap.Save(@"C:\Test.jpg");
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Are you getting exceptions? Errors? It is not clear from what you posted where the issue is. Please read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) and revise the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

```
if(filename.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1)
   bitmap.Save(textBox4.Text);
else
   MessageBox.Show("Error: the file name contains invalid chars");
```

**EDIT:**

> That doesn't work. Because it must save the file to C: and the file
>   must be a jpg image, just like my code. I know how to solve this with
>   SaveFileDialog, but i don't want to see any dialog saving the file and
>   the users must not change where i want to save it.

```
if(filename.IndexOfAny(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()) != -1)
   bitmap.Save(@"C:\" + textBox4.Text + ".jpg");
else
   MessageBox.Show("Error: the file name contains invalid chars");
```

Comment: @Oded if u don't know how that works, then I would suggest picking up a book on C# before continuing

Comment: @ColeJohnson - I am trying to get the OP to add some detail to the question. Just giving an answer like that will not educate the question answer much. If the person answering can add detail, explaining _why_ they feel that will work (the mechanism employed in the answer), in order to help educate others.

Comment: @Oded I simply answered to the question. I will edit my answer if the question changes.

Comment: @Fuex - All I am saying is that a more useful answer _for everyone reading_, not just the OP, would include your explanation.

Comment: Wouldn't work if `textBox4.Text` contained some of `Path.InvalidPathChars`

Comment: That doesn't work. Because it must save the file to C: and the file must be a jpg image, just like my code. I know how to solve this with SaveFileDialog, but i don't want to see any dialog saving the file and the users must not change where i want to save it.

Comment: bitmap.Save(@"C:\" + textBox4.Text + ".jpg");

Thank you very much. =)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that, use the SaveFileDialog component. It will deal with paths, valid names, pick up special folders like documents etc..

Answer (score 1):

When using a text entered by a user, you should remove any illegal characters from the string, otherwise you will get an exception when trying to create a file with that name.

```
private static string RemoveInvalidChars(string s, char[] invalidChars) {
    foreach (char ch in invalidChars) {
        s = s.Replace(ch.ToString(), "");
    }
    return s.Trim();
}
```

Using this helper method, you can save the bitmap like this

```
string path = RemoveInvalidChars(Path.GetDirectoryName(textBox4.Text),
                                 Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
string filename = RemoveInvalidChars(Path.GetFileName(textBox4.Text),
                                     Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
if (filename.Length > 0) {
    if (path.Length > 0) {
        filename = Path.Combine(path, filename);
    }
    bitmap.Save(filename);
} else {
    // not a valid filename
}
```